# Show payment popup on order submit

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm struggling to make an integration of my payment gateway's API on WooCommerce. I want when the customer presses the "Submit Order" button, a pop up to appear (asking for the credit card info). Is there a function such as payment_fields() that handles that? I'm not familiar with WooCommerce's API and functions and I cannot find any relevant docs anywhere....!

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you intercept the form from processing, trigger a modal box which asks the user these questions, and then on submit send the correct data to the WC_Payment_Gateway class?

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html

Have a look at the property list